# Lync client implementation using UCMA

Tags: .net, lync-2010

I am very new at Lync development. Is it possible to implement simple .NET console client for Lync 2010 that allows me to start audio conversation using UCMA 3.0? The problem is that I have no direct access to Lync server machine. I can only log in as client.

Answer (score 0):

you can start developing for Lync easily all you need is deep knowledge in .NET Language i.e. C# also
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
- Microsoft Lync SDK 2010
- UCMA 3.0 API

and you can use the following link it is Quick Start samples using UCMA
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh364906.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Definitely possible. The sample applications are invaluable (especially InstantMessagingBot). You'll be creating a UserEndpoint rather than an ApplicationEndpoint, and use ClientPlatformSettings instead of ServerPlatformSettings.

Also the following two books are an excellent reference
[http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Communications-Development-Microsoft-Programmer/dp/0470939036](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470939036)
[http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Unified-Communications-Microsoft%C2%AE-Office/dp/B008SM2EHE/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1363286031&sr=1-2&keywords=programming+for+unified+communications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008SM2EHE)

The second is available for free as a PDF if you google the title + pdf.  It's for UCMA 2.0 but it's still useful information.